# Gatsby filter with wordpress wpml langauge not working

Tags: wordpress, graphql, gatsby, wpml, wordpress-graphql

I have a wordpress headless setup to work with gatsby static site genetator. The data is coming correclty when queried from wordpress console.

```
{
    categories (where : {language: "fr"}){
    nodes {
      id,
      databaseId,
      name,
      uri
    }
  }
}
```

Same data is not coming when queried from gatsby graphql query:

```
{
  allWpCategory (filter : {language : {code : {eq : "fr"}}}){
    nodes {
      id,
      name,
      uri,
      databaseId,
      languageCode
    }
  }
}
```

However the en content appears when filter is changed to "en":

```
{
  allWpCategory (filter : {language : {code : {eq : "en"}}}){
    nodes {
      id,
      name,
      uri,
      databaseId,
      languageCode
    }
  }
}
```

I have verified all wpml configurations and the languages are properly configured and associated with posts. Also categories are having FR version content setup.